# Inheriting Multiple Classes in F#

Tags: swift, inheritance, f#, uicollectionview, superclass

I have the following class definition in Swift:

```
class LandlordHome : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

}
```

I'm trying to create it in F#, however the inheritance pattern in F# only allows me to inherit one class like this:

```
[<Register ("LandlordHome")>]
type LandlordHome (handle:IntPtr) =
inherit UIViewController (handle)
```

If I try to add additional classes like this:

```
[<Register ("LandlordHome")>]
type LandlordHome (handle:IntPtr) =
inherit UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource (handle)
```

this throws an error.

Comment: I have no experience with F#. But note that LandlordHome inherits from the *single class* UIViewController, and conforms to additional *protocols.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` are not `class`es, but `protocol`s, which are like `interface`s in `F#`

So your could should look something like this (abstract code):

```
[<Register ("LandlordHome")>]
type LandlordHome (handle:IntPtr) =
    inherit UIViewController (handle)
    interface UICollectionViewDelegate with
       // implementation of UICollectionViewDelegate
    interface UICollectionViewDataSource with
       // implementation of UICollectionViewDataSource
```